# Apache a2enmod ssl won't enable

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2

I tried to enter a command:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Then I got:

```
 Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
    ERROR: Module setenvif not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/setenvif.load is a real file, not touching it
    ERROR: Could not enable dependency setenvif for ssl, aborting
```

There no results in google and bing, this problem is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: It needs to delete existing file setenvif.load, and execute command again, it fixes the problem.

It needs to apply some files which require to module ssl, delete them.

Comment: I'd like to specify that you have to delete /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/setenvif.load
not /etc/apach2/mod-available/setenvif.load